# PIP (Picture-In-Picture) javascript video location

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video, picture-in-picture

I am using `requestPictureInPicture` to popup the html video element but the problem is the video is always open in the bottom right of the page. I was hoping to open it up

Is it possible to open the PiP (Picture-in-Picture) video anywhere else thats not the bottom right? I want to open it on the bottom left or curios if there is any other place we can open it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Picture in picture is just an implementation of system picture in picture functionality and as per standard does not support window position or placement of any sort

https://www.w3.org/TR/picture-in-picture